# In R, how do I find the optimal variable to maximize or minimize correlation between several datasets

Tags: r, optimization, correlation

I am able to do this easily in Excel, but my dataset has gotten too large. In excel, I would use solver.

```
Column A,B,C,D = random numbers 
Column E = random number (which I want to maximize the correlation to) 
Column F = A*x+B*y+C*z+D*j where x,y,z,j are coefficients resulted from solver In a separate cell, I would have correl(E,F)
```

In solver, I would set the objective of correl(C,D) to max, by changing variables x,y and setting certain constraints:

```
1.  A,B,C,D have to be between 0 and 1
2.  A+B+C+D = 1
```

How can I do this in R? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since most optimization routines work best with no constraints, 
you can transform (reparametrize) the problem of finding 
four numbers, x, y, z, j,
constrained to be between 0 and 1 and to sum up to 1, 
into the problem of finding three real numbers q1, q2, q3
(with no constraints).
For instance, if we have a function s that maps the real line R
to the interval (0,1), 
the following does the trick:

```
  x = s(q1)
  y = (1-x) * s(q2)
  z = (1-x-y) * s(q3)
  j = 1-x-y-z
```

It is probably easier to understand in two dimensions:
in this case, the set of points (x,y,z)
with coordinates between 0 and 1 and summing up to 1
is a triangle and s(q1),s(q2) form a coordinate system
for points in that triangle.

```
# Sample data
A <- rnorm(100)
B <- rnorm(100)
C <- rnorm(100)
D <- rnorm(100)
E <- rnorm(100)
f <- function(p) cor(p[1]*A + p[2]*B + p[3]*C + p[4]*D, E)

# Unconstrained optimization
optim(
  c(1,1,1,1)/4, # Starting values
  f,            # Function to maximize
  control=list(fnscale=-1) # Maximize (default is to minimize)
)

# Transform the parameters
sigmoid <- function(x) exp(x) / ( 1 + exp(x) )
convert <- function(p) {
  q1 <- sigmoid(p[1])
  q2 <- (1-q1) * sigmoid(p[2])
  q3 <- (1-q1-q2) * sigmoid(p[3])
  q4 <- 1-q1-q2-q3 
  c(q1,q2,q3,q4)
}

# Optimization
g <- function(p) f(convert(p))
p <- optim(c(0,0,0,0), g, control=list(fnscale=-1))
convert(p$par)
```

Comment: Nice answer but probably assumes the 'average' user (defined as me :-) )  knows a lot more about constrained vs. unconstrained configurations.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I have added some explanations: is it more understandable?

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the easiest way first time thru, but I wrote a function which uses the package `BB` to back-solve systems of equations.  You can download it:  [http://home.comcast.net/~cgwcgw/ktsolve.R](http://home.comcast.net/%7Ecgwcgw/ktsolve.R)   .

### update

Of course comcast's home pages are long gone. Go get the "ktsolve" package at CRAN

There's reasonably comprehensible documentation in the comments at the top of the source file.  Basically, you create a function whose outputs are the results of all your equations, feed `ktsolve` a set of "knowns" and a list of the variables which are 'unknowns,' and rather like the commercial app "TK!Solver"  it finds the answers for you.
If you do decide to try this out, feel free to email me for help in using it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you might want is to do a [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). This finds coefficients to multiply your predictors by (your predictors in this case being A, B, C and D) so that the fitted values produced have the smallest possible squared difference from the actual values. This is not quite the same as maximising the correlation between the fitted and actual values, but it does the same job. Here's an example- the coefficients of a, b, c and d anre equivalent to your x y z j

```
> a <- rnorm(10)
> b <- rnorm(10)
> c <- rnorm(10)
> d <- rnorm(10)
> e <- rnorm(10)
> lm(e~ a + b + c +d)

Call:
lm(formula = e ~ a + b + c + d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            a            b            c            d  
    -0.2881      -0.1898      -0.7282       0.2121       0.2758
```

However, this linear model has an extra parameter, the intercept. The intercept is a constant added to all the fitted values, so that the fitted values are actually: 
    fitted = constant + a*x + b*y + c*z +d*j

You can run a linear regression without fitting an intercept by running:

> lm(e~ -1 + a + b + c +d)