# In R, how do I find the optimal variable to minimise the correlation between two datasets

Tags: r, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In R, how do I find the optimal variable to maximize or minimize correlation between several datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592369/in-r-how-do-i-find-the-optimal-variable-to-maximize-or-minimize-correlation-bet)

This can be done in Excel, but my dataset has gotten too large. In excel, I would use solver.

I have 5 variables and I want to recreate a weighted average of these 5 variables so that they have the lowest correlation to a 6th variable.

Column A,B,C,D,E = random numbers

Column F = random number (which I want to minimise the correlation to)

Column G = A*wi1+B*wi2+C*2i3+D*wi4+wi5*E

where wi1 to wi5 are coefficients resulted from solver In a separate cell, I would have correl(F,G)

This is all achieved with the following constraints in mind:
1.  A,B,C,D, E have to be between 0 and 1
2.  A+B+C+D+E= 1

I'd like to print the results of this so that I can have an efficient frontier type chart.
How can I do this in R? Thanks for the help.

Comment: If these two questions are in fact by the same person, you should know that using multiple accounts like this is frequently frowned upon.

Comment: How is this an exact duplicate? It's similar theme but I want to minimise and create a efficient style frontier. If you search the net i cannot find the answer

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the other thread mentioned by Vincent and I think I have a better solution. I hope it is correct. As Vincent points out, your biggest problem is that the optimization tools for such non-linear problems do not offer a lot of flexibility for dealing with your constraints. Here, you have two types of constraints: 1) all your weights must be `>= 0`, and 2) they must sum to `1`.

The `optim` function has a `lower` option that can take care of your first constraint. For the second constraint, you have to be a bit creative: you can force your weights to sum to one by scaling them inside the function to be minimized, i.e. rewrite your correlation function as `function(w) cor(X %*% w / sum(w), Y)`.

```
# create random data
n.obs <- 100
n.var <- 6
X <- matrix(runif(n.obs * n.var), nrow = n.obs, ncol = n.var)
Y <- matrix(runif(n.obs), nrow = n.obs, ncol = 1)

# function to minimize
correl <- function(w)cor(X %*% w / sum(w), Y)
# inital guess
w0 <- rep(1 / n.var, n.var)
# optimize
opt <- optim(par = w0, fn = correl, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = 0)
optim.w <- opt$par / sum(opt$par)
```