# Optimization with Constraints

Tags: r

I am working with the output from a model in which there are parameter estimates that may not follow a-priori expectations. I would like to write a function that forces these utility estimates back in line with those expectations. To do this, the function should minimize the sum of the squared deviance between the starting values and the new estimates. Since we have a-priori expections, the optimization should be subject to the following constraints:

```
B0 < B1
B1 < B2
...
Bj < Bj+1
```

For example, the raw parameter estimates below are flipflopped for B2 and B3. The columns `Delta` and `Delta^2` show the deviance between the original parameter estimate and the new coefficient. I am trying to minimize the column `Delta^2`. I've coded this up in Excel and shown how Excel's Solver would optimize this problem providing the set of constraints:

```
Beta    BetaRaw    Delta    Delta^2    BetaNew
B0       1.2       0        0          1.2
B1       1.3       0        0          1.3
B2       1.6       -0.2     0.04       1.4
B3       1.4       0        0          1.4
B4       2.2       0        0          2.2
```

After reading through `?optim` and `?constrOptim`, I'm not able to grok how to set this up in R. I'm sure I'm just being a bit dense, but could use some pointers in the right direction!

3/24/2012 - Added bounty since I'm not smart enough to translate the first answer.

Here's some R code that should be on the right path. Assuming that the betas start with:

```
betas <- c(1.2,1.3,1.6,1.4,2.2)
```

I want to minimize the following function such that `b0 <= b1 <= b2 <= b3 <= b4`

```
f <- function(x) {
  x1 <- x[1]
  x2 <- x[2]
  x3 <- x[3]
  x4 <- x[4]
  x5 <- x[5]

 loss <- (x1 - betas[1]) ^ 2 + 
         (x2 - betas[2]) ^ 2 + 
         (x3 - betas[3]) ^ 2 + 
         (x4 - betas[4]) ^ 2 +
         (x5 - betas[5]) ^ 2    

  return(loss)
}
```

To show that the function works, the loss should be zero if we pass the original betas in:

```
> f(betas)
[1] 0
```

And relatively large with some random inputs:

```
> set.seed(42)
> f(rnorm(5))
[1] 8.849329
```

And minimized at the values I was able to calculate in Excel:

```
> f(c(1.2,1.3,1.4,1.4,2.2))
[1] 0.04
```

Comment: On reflection, you are in fact describing an ordered logistic regression (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit). In package `MASS` the function `polr` can solve this type of problem. There is an example at http://www.stat.washington.edu/quinn/classes/536/S/polrexample.html. Kenneth Train describes this well in his book "Discrete Choice Methods with Simulation"

Comment: @Andrie - perhaps I just need my morning coffee, but I'm having a hard time connecting the dots between the polr example and what I need to do here. With `polr()`, isn't the goal to predict a set of proportional odds ratios? I've got Ken Train's book sitting on my bookshelf (collecting dust), so I'll give it a whirl as well. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrie +1 for Train.  Note it's available online in PDF form as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1.** 
Since the objective is quadratic and the constraints linear,
you can use `solve.QP`.

It finds the `b` that minimizes

```
(1/2) * t(b) %*% Dmat %*% b - t(dvec) %*% b
```

under the constraints

```
t(Amat) %*% b >= bvec.
```

Here, we want `b` that minimizes

```
sum( (b-betas)^2 ) = sum(b^2) - 2 * sum(b*betas) + sum(beta^2)
                   = t(b) %*% t(b) - 2 * t(b) %*% betas + sum(beta^2).
```

Since the last term, `sum(beta^2)`, is constant, we can drop it,
and we can set

```
Dmat = diag(n)
dvec = betas.
```

The constraints are

```
b[1] <= b[2]
b[2] <= b[3]
...
b[n-1] <= b[n]
```

i.e.,

```
-b[1] + b[2]                       >= 0
      - b[2] + b[3]                >= 0
               ...
                   - b[n-1] + b[n] >= 0
```

so that `t(Amat)` is

```
[ -1  1                ]
[    -1  1             ]
[       -1  1          ]
[             ...      ]
[                -1  1 ]
```

and `bvec` is zero.

This leads to the following code.

```
# Sample data
betas <- c(1.2, 1.3, 1.6, 1.4, 2.2)

# Optimization
n <- length(betas)
Dmat <- diag(n)
dvec <- betas
Amat <- matrix(0,nr=n,nc=n-1)
Amat[cbind(1:(n-1), 1:(n-1))] <- -1
Amat[cbind(2:n,     1:(n-1))] <-  1
t(Amat)  # Check that it looks as it should
bvec <- rep(0,n-1)
library(quadprog)
r <- solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec)

# Check the result, graphically
plot(betas)
points(r$solution, pch=16)
```

**2.** 
You can use `constrOptim` in the same way (the objective function can be arbitrary, but the constraints have to be linear).

**3.**
More generally, you can use `optim` if you reparametrize the problem
into a non-constrained optimization problem, 
for instance

```
b[1] = exp(x[1])
b[2] = b[1] + exp(x[2])
...
b[n] = b[n-1] + exp(x[n-1]).
```

There are a few examples 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592369/in-r-how-do-i-find-the-optimal-variable-to-maximize-or-minimize-correlation-bet/9593809#9593809)
or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666120/constrain-optimisation-problems-in-r).

Comment: thanks for the response. I know everything I need is contained above, but I'm not seeing it. Specifically, 1) how/where are the constraints specified, and 2) where do I input a function to calculate the deviance between b_0 and the estimates?

Comment: This is explained in `?solve.QP`:
it finds the `b` that minimizes 
`(1/2) * t(b) %*% Dmat %*% b - t(dvec) %*% b`
under the constraints
`t(Amat) %*% b >= bvec`.
The first two arguments of `solve.QP` define the objective function,
the last two the constraints.
You "just" have to put your problem under this form...

Comment: Hmmm, alright - that helps confirm my interpretation of the help page. I guess I just don't think well enough in matrices to see how I should set up `Dmat` and `Amat`...I'll keep thinking through this. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you're still following this, but any more specific insight to my specific optimization would be appreciated.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the insight, this actually makes a bit of sense now too!

Comment: One last follow up - do you have any recommendations for a gentle introduction / reference text for this sort of analysis? You know, the whole teach a man to fish thing...I pulled up the first reference in the help page for solve.QP, but it looks a bit dense.

Comment: I usually advise 
Cornuejols and Tutuncu's 
[Optimization methods in finance](http://www.amazon.com/Optimization-Methods-Finance-Mathematics-Risk/dp/0521861705).
It does not assume any prior knowledge in operations research,
is rather exhaustive,
but the examples are limited to finance.
You also can try to ask on 
[CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books):
they may have more general or elementary references.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is starting to take form, but still has some bugs. Based on the conversation in chat with @Joran, it seems I can include a conditional that will set the loss function to an arbitrarily large value if the values are not in order. This seems to work IF the discrepancy occurs between the first two coefficients, but not thereafter. I'm having a hard time parsing out why that would be the case.

Function to minimize:

```
f <- function(x, x0) {
  x1 <- x[1]
  x2 <- x[2]
  x3 <- x[3]
  x4 <- x[4]
  x5 <- x[5]

 loss <- (x1 - x0[1]) ^ 2 + 
         (x2 - x0[2]) ^ 2 + 
         (x3 - x0[3]) ^ 2 + 
         (x4 - x0[4]) ^ 2 +
         (x5 - x0[5]) ^ 2    

  #Make sure the coefficients are in order
  if any(diff(c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)) > 0) loss = 10000000

  return(loss)
}
```

Working example (sort of, it seems the loss would be minimized if `b0 = 1.24`?):

```
> betas <- c(1.22, 1.24, 1.18, 1.12, 1.10)
> optim(betas, f, x0 = betas)$par
[1] 1.282 1.240 1.180 1.120 1.100
```

Non-working example (note that the third element is still larger than the second:

```
> betas <- c(1.20, 1.15, 1.18, 1.12, 1.10)
> optim(betas, f, x0 = betas)$par
[1] 1.20 1.15 1.18 1.12 1.10
```

Comment: For increasing numbers, as in the original question, 
you probably need a penalty if `any(diff(x))<0)`, 
rather than `>0`.

Comment: Since the penalty for the constraint breaches is constant,
the optimization algorithm does not know in which direction 
to modify an incorrect solution to improve it, and could
conclude that, since the loss function looks constant,
the current value, even if it is high, is a local minimum.
You can make the penalty dependent on the amplitude of the breaches. 
`f <- function(x, x0) {
  loss <- sum((x-x0)^2);
  if( any(diff(x)<0) ) {
    loss <- loss + 1e9*sum(pmax(0,-diff(x)))
  };
  loss
};
optim(betas, f, x0 = betas)$par`