# Extreme Value Theory (Type II&III case) problem with optimization (using R)

Tags: r, optimization, statistics, log-likelihood

I'm doing a project on Extreme Value Theory in R and I'm having to code my own maximum likelihood estimates for the parameters for each of the 3 distributions.

The mle's for extreme value distributions don't have analytic solutions, they must be approximated numerically. The Gumbel case was easy, as I could get one parameter by itself and use the result to optimize the other parameter numerically.

For the Fréchet and Weibull cases, you have to optimize more than one parameter simultaneously. I'm trying to use the optim() function in R but getting very weird results. I'm not sure if this is a problem with my code, a problem with my understanding of optim(), or with the theory itself (or some combination of the 3).

Anyway, here's my code:

```
library(evd) #using this for frechet random variables

#generate maxima from 2 distributions: 1st should converge to Frechet, 2nd to Weibull
Mfrechet<-function (m) {
  d1<-matrix(rfrechet(1000000),nrow=m)
  apply(d1,1,max)/(1000000/m)
} 

Munif <- function (m) {
  d1<-matrix(runif(10000000),nrow=m)
  n<-ncol(d1)
    Xn<-apply(d1,1,max)
  n*Xn -n +1
}

x1<-Mfrechet(10000)
x2<-Munif(10000)

#negative log-likelihood for frechet
lf.fr <- function(y) {
  x<-x1
  n<-length(x1)
  a<-y[1]
  b<-y[2]
  g<-y[3]
  -(n*log(g)+n*g*log(b)-(g+1)*sum(log(x-a),na.rm=T)-sum((b/log(x-a))^g,na.rm=T))
}

#negative log likelihood function for weibull
lf.weibull <- function(y) {
  x<-x2
  n<-length(x2)
  a<-y[1]
  b<-y[2]
  g<-y[3]
  -(n*log(g)+n*g*log(b)+(g-1)*sum(log(a-x),na.rm=T)-sum(((a-x)/b)^g,na.rm=T))
}

optim(c(1,1,1),lf.fr)
optim(c(1,1,1),lf.weibull)
```

The results are way off, especially compared with fevd from extRemes package:

```
library(extRemes)
fevd(x1)
fevd(x2)
```

I tried changing the starting values for optim, but it gives me wildly different results but not close to correct ones. I've used getAnywhere to look at most gev fitting in different packages, they mostly use optim as well, but they are pretty difficult to sort through.

Can anyone show me where I am going wrong? And hopefully a way to fix it that isn't too complicated...

Comment: I'm probably not understanding something here, but Weibull has support on the positive reals and your `x2` has negative values. Also your likelihood functions don't look anything like the LL for either Frechet or Weibull. For instance Weibull is a 2-parameter distribution. Where did the LL expressions come from?

Comment: I am not sure if you can see this [link](http://shorturl.at/alqzN) (apologies for my terrible handwriting), but I think the difference is that the Weibull distribution I'm looking (Type III GEV distribution) at has a location parameter.

Your point about the support is well taken though, I will try to work on changing that and see if it works better.

Comment: OK I see now. [This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution) has a good summary. I'll look into it some more this weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is two-fold. First, the GEV distribution has support which depends on the parameters. So if you know the parameters, it is a simple matter to calculate the support, but if you are searching for the parameters in an optimiizer is is easy to land on a combination which is inconsistent with your data. Your loglik functions need to deal with that.

Second, whether GEV corresponds to Weibull or Frechet depends on the shape parameter, xi (xi > 0 implies Frechet; xi < 0 implies Weibull). So you need to use an optimizer which allows you set lower and upper bounds on the parameters. If you use `optim(...)` your only choice is "L-BFGS-B". Unfortunately, this method is somewhat fragile (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387330/errors-when-attempting-constrained-optimisation-using-optim)). An alternative, identified in that same post, is `nmkb(...)` from the `dfoptim` package.

Here is a working example, based on the parameterization of the GEV distribution defined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution).

```
library(evd)
library(dfoptim)
#
ll = \(par, x) {
  mu <- par[1]; sigma <- par[2]; xi <- par[3]
  s <- (x - mu)/sigma
  t <- (1 + xi*s)^(-1/xi)
  f <- t^(xi+1) * exp(-t) / sigma
  if(any(is.na(f)) | any(f <= 0)) return(1e6)
  return (-sum(log(f)))
}
par    <- c(mu=0, sigma=.5, xi=-0.1)
result <- nmkb(par, ll, lower = c(-Inf, 0, -Inf), upper = c(Inf, Inf, 0), x=x2)
result$par
## [1] -0.001692221  0.998771474 -0.997121661
fevd(x2)$results$par
##     location        scale        shape 
## -0.001711532  0.998739426 -0.997070437
#
par    <- c(mu=0, sigma=0.5, xi=+0.1)
result <- nmkb(par, ll, lower = c(-Inf, 0, 0), upper = c(Inf, Inf, Inf), x=x1)
result$par
## [1] 0.9997442 1.0003228 1.0004027
fevd(x1)$results$r
##  location     scale     shape 
## 0.9999759 1.0005464 1.0003256
```

Note that you did not set the seed for the random number generator in your post, so your `x1` and `x2` will be different. I used `set.seed(1)`.

Comment: I made a function that seemed to work also:

`gev1<-function(x) {
  n <- as.matrix(rep(1, length(x)))
  if(min(x)<0){
    x=x-min(x)+1
  }
  else{x=x}
  y1<-function(y) {
    a<-n*y[1]
    b<-n*y[2]
    g<-n*y[3]
   z<-1 + g * ((x - a)/b)
   if (any(z <= 0) || any(b <= 0)) 
     return(10^40)
   sum(log(b)) + sum((1 + g * ((x - a)/b))^(-1/g)) + sum(log(1 + g * ((x - a)/b)) * (1/g + 1))
  }
 optim(c(1,1,1),y1)
}
`
Your note about the support really helped. Yours looks a bit different than mine, but I will look at it in more detail tomorrow.

Extremely helpful, thanks!